# wpf Treeview with three levels in

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a beginner and trying to create my first application that contain a treeView that has three levels
First level show the name of process
Second level show its modules and threads which are fix
Third level contain sub modules and subthreads

```
 proc1      
    Module      
      subMod1     
   Thread      
      thread1                        
 proc2                                                                            
   Module
     submod1
   Thread
     subThread
```

this is **xmal.cs** file

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public MainWindow()
    {


        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            Module mod = new Module
            {
                modulelist = new List<moduleList>() { new moduleList {           Name = "mod1" } ,
             new moduleList { Name = "mod1" } }
            };
            Thread th = new Thread
            {
                threadlist = new List<threadList>() { new threadList { Name = "thread1" } ,
             new threadList { Name = "thread1" } }
            };
            ProcName proc1 = new ProcName { Name = "proc" + i, mod = new Module(), th = new Thread() };
            tv.DataContext = proc1;
        }
    }

    public class ProcName
    {

        public string Name
        { get; set; }
        public Module mod = new Module();
        public Thread th = new Thread();

    }
    public class Module
    {
        public string Name = "Module";
        public List<moduleList> modulelist
        { get; set; }
    }
    public class moduleList
    {
        public string Name
        { get; set; }
    }
    public class Thread {
        public string Name = "Thread";
        public List<threadList> threadlist
        { get; set; }
    }
    public class threadList
    {
        public string Name
        { get; set; }
    }


}
```

This is **xmal** file

```
<TreeView Name="tv" ItemsSource="{Binding}">

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ProcName}">
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <!-- child node will be a MasterAction -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Module}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <!-- leaf will be a SlaveAction -->
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate ItemSource ="{Binding moduleList} ">
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Thread}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <!-- leaf will be a SlaveAction -->
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate ItemSource   ="{Binding threadList} ">
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
</Window>
```

I know that it's not right way but tried to do it like this
How to use it properly?

Comment: your data classes don't match your tree, that's the first problem. Can one process have more than one thread? More than one Module?

Comment: yes one process has multiple modules and threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Interface` to get this working.

**xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var subNodes = new List<ITreeNode>
        {
            new SubNode { Name = "Sub Node 1" },
            new SubNode { Name = "Sub Node 2" },
            new SubNode { Name = "Sub Node 3" },
            new SubNode { Name = "Sub Node 4" }
        };
        var nodes = new List<ITreeNode>
        {
            new Thread { Name = "Thread 1", ChildNodes = subNodes },
            new Thread { Name = "Thread 2", ChildNodes = subNodes },
            new Module { Name = "Module 1", ChildNodes = subNodes },
            new Module { Name = "Module 2", ChildNodes = subNodes }
        };
        var processes = new List<Process>
        {
            new Process{ Name = "Process1", ChildNodes = nodes },
            new Process{ Name = "Process2", ChildNodes = nodes }
        };
        TreeView.ItemsSource = processes;
    }
}
public interface ITreeNode
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<ITreeNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
public class Process : ITreeNode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<ITreeNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
public class Module : ITreeNode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ITreeNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
public class Thread : ITreeNode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public List<ITreeNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
public class SubNode : ITreeNode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ITreeNode> ChildNodes { get => null; set => throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

**xaml**

If you do not need different template for level, you can use

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeView">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>            
</TreeView>
```

If you need different template for levels, you can use something like this,

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeView">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Process}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat='{}{0} '}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID, StringFormat=(ID: {0})}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Module}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Thread}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat='{}{0} '}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID, StringFormat=(ID: {0})}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SubNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thank u so much it works perfectly but I am little bit confuse because in my case module and thread does not share same subnodes and the reason of this is that each process has different threads and different modules

Comment: You can create another `SubNode` and use it like `Module` and `Thread` class. It'll be

        `var subNodes = new List<ITreeNode>
        {
            new SubNode1 { Name = "Sub Node 1" },
            new SubNode1 { Name = "Sub Node 2" },
            new SubNode2 { Name = "Sub Node 3" },
            new SubNode2 { Name = "Sub Node 4" }
        };`

Comment: I have done something like this add a subclass for module public class `SubNode1 : ITreeNode
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<ITreeNode> ChildNodes { get => null; set => throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
    } then create its variable var subNodes1 = new List<ITreeNode>
        {
            new SubNode1 { Name = "Sub Node1 1" },} and then use it as new Module { Name = "Module 2", ChildNodes = subNodes1 }` but it does not work well

Comment: and output for subnode1 is `wpfexample.SubNode1`

Comment: I found the error. Now it is resolved and work perfectly thanks for help and effort